# jQuery: equal height columns in fluid layout on resize

Tags: jquery

I'm having problems with a fluid equal height column layout.

```
jQuery(function($){

        var qMetaHeight, qBodyHeight, qAnswerCount; 

        function gameResize() {

            qMetaHeight = $('.taskMeta').height();
            qBodyHeight = $('.taskBody').height();
            qAnswerCount = $('.answerCount').height();
            if( qMetaHeight > qBodyHeight ) {
                $('.taskBody').height(qMetaHeight);
            }
            else if ( qMetaHeight < qBodyHeight )  {
                $('.taskMeta').height(qBodyHeight);
                $('.bestMatches').height(qBodyHeight-qAnswerCount);
            }

            $('#test').html("taskMeta: " + qMetaHeight + "<br>taskBody: " + qBodyHeight + "<br>answerCount: " + qAnswerCount);
        };
        gameResize();
        $(window).resize(gameResize);

});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/klavina/QPkxu/1/

This works perfectly on page load, but fails miserably on page resize.

2 issues:

- Sometimes (not always) when decreasing the window's width it simply doesn't work at all: http://grab.by/iRcm.
- When it does work and the user decreases the window's size a lot and then again increases it - the height stays at maximum: http://grab.by/iRcq. I'm guessing I need to reset the height set by jQuery first, how can I do that?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See this: http://jsfiddle.net/QPkxu/7/

```
jQuery(function($){

        var qMetaHeight, qBodyHeight, qAnswerCount; 
        var org_qMetaHeight = $('.taskMeta').height();
        var org_qBodyHeight = $('.taskBody').height();
        $('.taskBody').css("min-height", $('.taskMeta').height());
        function gameResize() {

            qMetaHeight = $('.taskMeta').height();
            qBodyHeight = $('.taskBody').height();
            qAnswerCount = $('.answerCount').height();
    $('.taskMeta').height(qBodyHeight);
    $('.bestMatches').height(qBodyHeight-qAnswerCount);
            //if( qMetaHeight > qBodyHeight ) {
                //$('.taskBody').height(qMetaHeight);
            //}
        //  else if ( qMetaHeight < qBodyHeight )  {          
                //$('.taskMeta').height(qBodyHeight);
                //$('.bestMatches').height(qBodyHeight-qAnswerCount);
            //}

            $('#test').html("taskMeta: " + qMetaHeight + "<br>taskBody: " + qBodyHeight + "<br>answerCount: " + qAnswerCount);
        };
        gameResize();
        $(window).resize(gameResize);

});
```

CSS:

```
    .taskBody {
        background: #f00;
        margin-right: 242px;
    }

    .taskMeta {
        float: right;
        width: 232px;
        background: #f00;
    }

    .answerCount {
        background: #000;
        color: #fff;
    }

    .bestMatches {
        background: #ccc;
    }
```

Comment: Thanks, but this doesn't really solve my problem.

My actual code is more complex and I cannot use a faux column with CSS  background; the .bestMatches needs to change height.